# How do you add a variable Count on the end of a $row->variable?

Tags: php, sql, variables

We are trying to make life easier on one of our website coded platforms.
There are 8 rows in the database, each with 1-4 at the end of them.

ie.  childrensrange1, childrensrange2 and so on.
Then childrennumber1, childrennumber2...

But I don't want to be creating a ton of code, so I have started writing this.  But I cannot work out how to assign the number to the end of the $row->variable.

Look at the row starting with: $childrenamountrow
I need it to query the database for $row->childrenamount1, then $row->childrenamount2 and so on.

I'm sure I have done this before, but I cannot remember how to do it.
This block should cover all 4 blocks of age ranges rather than reams of code for each set.

````
$countchild = 1;
while ($countchild <=4) {
    echo "<tr><td><select name='childrensrange$countchild'>";
    $querychildren = ("SELECT * FROM `childrensagerange` ORDER BY id");
    $resultchildren = $pdo->query($querychildren); 
    while ($rowchildren = $resultchildren->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) { 
        $childrenrangerow = "$rowchildren->agerange"."$countchild";
        echo "<option value='$rowchildren->agerange'";
        if ($rowchildren->agerange == $childrenrangerow) { echo " selected='selected'";}
        echo ">$rowchildren->agerange</option>";
    }
    echo "</td><td>";
    $childrenamountrow = "$row->childrenamount$countchild";
    echo "<input type='text' name='childrenamount$countchild' value='$childrenamountrow'></td></tr>";
    $countchild ++;
}

echo "</table>```
````

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php // Or fetch the data as an array instead of an object to begin with, then you only have to do basic string concatenation on the key that you use to access the entries.

Comment: Sorry I'm not that clear.  I am a bit PHP rusty these days!  This needs to count up (only to 4), so how do I attach that to the end of the variable?

Comment: By using curly braces to access a property based on the name of that property being in some variable … the manual has examples.

Comment: Why not `SELECT * FROM `childrensagerange` ORDER BY agerange, id`. Then you can get it all back with one query

Comment: Also, won't you're not closing your `<select>` elements.

Comment: Fixed the `<select>` bit.  How do you do curly braces?  Do you literally do:
`$row->childrennumber{$countchild}` ?

Comment: $childrenamountrow = $row->childrenamount{$countchild};

Comment: `$childrenamountrow =array('$row->childrenamount1', '$row->childrenamount2', '$row->childrenamount3', '$row->childrenamount4');
$childrenamount = $childrenamountrow[$countchild];
echo "<input type='text' name='childrenamount$countchild' value='$childrenamount'>`
I did this but it just renders: $row->childrenamount1...... to 4 in the text field.  Not the value from the database.

Comment: I've have tried this too:
`$childrenamountrow = new childrenamountrow();
$childrenarray = array('$row->childrenamount1', '$row->childrenamount2', '$row->childrenamount3', '$row->childrenamount4');

echo "<input type='text' name='childrenamount$countchild' value='";
echo $childrenarray[$countchild] . "'></td></tr>";
  $countchild ++;`, but it still takes the row name rather than it's value into the array.

Answer (score 0):

why not something like this ?

```
for (var i=1;i<=4;i++) {
    $querychildren = ("SELECT childrensrange"+i+" FROM `childrensagerange` ORDER BY id");
    $resultchildren = $pdo->query($querychildren);
     (...)
}
```

Comment: The table is big, but this is just for four rows:
childrensrange1-4
childrensnumber1-4

I cannot do it with 4 DB queries.  The PHP query I wrote looks sound, it's just how to 'ask the database' for each row, without having to write four separate queries.

Comment: what are the column of your DB ? and what is the technology of your database ?

Comment: MySQL.  The column names are as described before.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, what you have and what you want precisely ex :
entry : col A | col B | ....
result : sum(col A) | average(col A) | ...

Comment: Apologies.  I thought I had been clear.  The database is fine.  I just need to query each row, thru a loop, using $countchildren++.  So $row->childrenrange1, is accessed to see the content via $row->childrenrange.$countchildren.  Meaning I have ONE query into the database, but accessed through a loop.

Comment: Ok you need to work with cursor on the DB. With the cursor for each call will get you the next result. (each time it's a call to the DB).
Otherwise it's not an SQL issue but a PHP solution to loop in the table

Comment: Actually no.  I've just coded it to that it queries it based on the count, within the single DB Query.  if $countchild = 1, then query field 1, and so on.

Comment: Also, how do I add the code that I have now tweaked, to show you what I have done, to see how you feel about it?

Secondly, it looks like I now cannot ask any more questions, and I've no idea why.... as I have one about TinyMCE.

Comment: there is an update link at the bottom of your question.